# Segmentation fault, 2-Dimensional Matrix, malloc

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, malloc

I'm trying to create a 2-Dimensional array using malloc.
My code seems correct but when I try to set values, I receive "Segmentation Fault" message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i, j;
    int **m = (int **) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    if(m == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        getchar();
        exit(-1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        m[i] = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

        if(m[i] == NULL){
            printf("Error");
            getchar();
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is C why tagged as C++

Comment: I think you should modify this statement to allocate an array of pointers: `int **m = (int **) malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));`

Comment: There is memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int **m = (int **) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

to

```
//---------------------------------------v
int **m = (int **) malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));
```

Your code will fail where size of `int` is not equal to size of pointer variable.

Comment: This could have been avoided by using the idiom `int **m = malloc(5 * sizeof *m);`

Answer (score 0):

some systems might have pointer size not equal to size of int. In your case your assuming that pointer is of size int

> int **m = (int **) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

change it to

> int **m =  malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));

always free memory after use. it will lead to memory leak.

Also don't cast when using malloc [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)